# Show a div on mouseover similar to the Google Chrome WebStore tiles

Tags: javascript, slider, tile

I would like to replicate the tile/slide effect from the Google Chrome WebStore on my website. Does anyone know of a script to do this? Or can you help me write one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [Mosaic](http://buildinternet.com/project/mosaic/). I've used it in the past, and it looks like exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! That is just what I'm looking for. I do have a question related to Mosaic. The image I am using is 200x250 and when I change the CSS for .mosaic-block to width:200px it has a strange border. How can I remove the border/padding?